# Can we use tags in firewall rules to allow traffic from pods in one gke cluster to pods in another that uses ip aliases?

Tags: networking, google-kubernetes-engine, firewall

I want to allow traffic from pods running on a gke cluster to another cluster (vpc native). Is it possible to do this using node tags? I gave it a try and it doesn't seem to work. It only works with source-ranges. Can someone please confirm this is the case? Or is it that I'm missing something?

I created two clusters (1.12.8-gke.10) one tagged with routing-test and the other tagged with central-cluster.

Using source-tags in the firewall rules won't work, while using source-ranges work.

For example, I have

```
gcloud container clusters create routing-test-1 --zone us-east1-d \
--no-enable-legacy-authorization --no-enable-basic-auth \
--tags routing-test --num-nodes 1

gcloud container clusters create routing-central --region us-east1 \
--no-enable-legacy-authorization --enable-ip-alias --no-enable-basic-auth \
--tags central-cluster --num-nodes 1
```

This works:

```
gcloud compute --project=cicd-clusters firewall-rules create allow-traffic-test-1 \
--direction=INGRESS --priority=1000 --network=default --action=ALLOW \
--rules=tcp:80 --source-ranges=10.16.0.0/14 --target-tags=central-cluster
```

While this won't work:

```
gcloud compute --project=cicd-clusters firewall-rules create allow-traffic-test-2 \
--direction=INGRESS --priority=1000 --network=default --action=ALLOW \
--rules=tcp:80 --source-tags=routing-test --target-tags=central-cluster
```

Comment: I'm not certain enough to mark this as an answer, but I am pretty sure that when you use VPC Native pods, they do not inherit the node's metadata such as network tags which is why this does not work properly. The pod appears as it's own network resource as opposed to NATed traffic from the node when VPC native is disabled. Pretty sure there is no way currently to apply network tags to the aliased IPs

Comment: Thank you @PatrickW. Because using target-tags worked, I expected that creating both clusters with native ip alias will allow me to use source-tags and target-tags to allow traffic between pods on these clusters, but that also didn't work.

Comment: the destination tags work because the incoming firewall rule applies at the node level, so the network tags of the node come into play, but egress traffic from pods count as their own thing. At first, I believed tags would still work as you do. I still believe they should. Def worth filing a feature request on Google's public issue tracker

Answer (score 0):

Nope. I tried :/

Pod traffic will emerge from the GKE node pool's `pod_ipv4_cidr_block` IP range, meaning it's not seen as coming from the GKE node (VM instance). This is because of [IP Alias](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/alias-ip) ranges in GKE which let traffic come from a VM instance, without coming from its main networking interface, so that each pod can have an IP on the VPC network.

You can make routing/FW rules based on that node pool CIDR range instead. :)